# Fast API path parameters from Enum Class

Tags: python, api, enum

```
from enum import Enum
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
```

Hi Defined a route and a Enum Class for the same but the Enum Class looks ugly.

```
class Subjects(str, Enum):
    path1="AcceptedEventRelation"
    path2="Account"
    path3="AccountChangeEvent"
    path4="AccountCleanInfo"
    path5="AccountContactRole"
    ...
    ...
    path100


@app.get("/subjects/{sobjectname:str}")
async def process_subjects(sobjectname:Subjects):
    endpoint_subjects = "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects"
    url_to_request = endpoint_subjects + "/" + sobjectname
    return {
        "subject" : sobjectname,
        "url_to_request": url_to_request
        }
```

Is there a better way to implement the Subjects Class. Thanks

Comment: The fact is that you need the LHS and RHS somewhere in your code, in some form. It can be a `list`, or `dict`, or in some other forms.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that you need the LHS and RHS somewhere in your code, in some form. It can be a `list`, or `dict`, or in some other forms.

For example:

```
from enum import Enum
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
some_dict = dict(
    path1="AcceptedEventRelation",
    path2="Account",
    path3="AccountChangeEvent",
    path4="AccountCleanInfo",
    path5="AccountContactRole"
)

Subjects = Enum('Subjects', some_dict)


@app.get("/subjects/{sobjectname}")
async def process_subjects(sobjectname: Subjects):
    endpoint_subjects = "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects"
    url_to_request = endpoint_subjects + "/" + sobjectname.value
    return {
        "subject": sobjectname,
        "url_to_request": url_to_request
    }
```

Here, the **`some_dict`** is the variable you need to ***generate***, which also looks ugly if there is a *100* items in it as the way you feel for the `Enum` class.

Comment: what is `MyDynamicEnum` referes to ? ..  when I call the endpoint I get, `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "MyDynamicEnum") to str
`

Comment: `MyDynamicEnum` is the class name

Comment: ok but how canI fix the above error

Comment: probably you should show the error traceback

Comment: error traceback added in the question, pls check

Comment: can you test my code once with your solution

Comment: updated the codebase.